# How do I use only the month from a date selected in a QCalendarWidget in an IF statement

Tags: c++, qt

In order to get to know C++ with Qt, I am making a few (very!) simple projects. The project that has me a bit stumped at the moment is what I call a "Meteorological Season Detector", which allows me to play around with QDate and QCalendarWidget. Upon running the application, the user is prompted to select a date from the QCalendarWidget. A QLabel will then output the season, e.g. "It's spring!". An IF statement is used to determine the season. As you will see in my code, I am only able to accurately detect the season within a certain year (2020). This is because I have yet to figure out how to "ignore" the year and day of the selected date in my IF statement, and use only the month. 
Having read the documentation, I feel like my answer might have something to do with `int QDate::month() const` but I have had no success. What I would like is some guidance as to whether or not I am going in the right direction and, if so, how to use `month()`, please.
In the southern hemisphere, meteorological spring, summer, autumn, and winter are September-November, December-February, March-May, and June-August respectively.

```
void Seasons::on_calendarWidget_clicked(const QDate &date)
{
    QDate may(2020, 5, 31);
    QDate august(2020, 8, 31);
    QDate november(2020, 11, 30);
    QDate february(2021, 2, 28);

    if(date > november && date < february)
    {
        ui->season->setText("It's summer!");
    }
    else if(date > february && date < may)
    {
        ui->season->setText("It's autumn!");
    }
    else if(date > may && date < august)
    {
        ui->season->setText("It's winter!");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->season->setText("It's spring!");
    }
}
```

Unsuccessful attempt at using `int QDate::month() const`:

```
    if(date > date::month(11) && date < date::month(3))
    {
        ui->season->setText("It's summer!");
    }
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Kaylyn\Desktop\QtCreator Projects\Seasons\seasons.cpp:24: error: 'date' is not a class or namespace
     if(date > date::month(11) && date < date::month(3))
                                         ^
```

Comment: `date.month()`, it returns `int`... Compare it against another int.

Comment: Why not `if (date.month() >= 3 && date.month() <= 5) { /*it's spring*/}`?

Comment: @hyde Thank you for your input. That was my intention, but I wasn't entirely sure how to type it. I have it now!

Comment: @vahancho That's how you do it, I see now! Thanks so much.